# Using import on nodejs on google cloud

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I have a nodejs app that uses `import` to tie files together.  Some of those files are also used on the client, so I don't want to switch to `require`.  I've been running it locally in node 13 with `"type":"module"` in `package.json`.  This works fine, and I'd kind of forgotten that `import` is still considered bleeding edge.

Then I tried to upload to Google Cloud (formerly appengine).

AFAICT, gcloud supports node12, and node12 support `import` *if you pass the `--experimental-modules` flag*.  But gcloud doesn't support passing flags.

Is there a way to make this work?  I don't mind messing with dockerfiles, but I'd rather not fork any large pieces of gcloud infrastructure.

Comment: Have you tried using the `.mjs` file extension as an alternative to setting `"type": "module"` in your `package.json`? More info can be found in the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/esm.html#esm_package_json_type_field)

Comment: Your link is to the node13 documentation.  I'm pretty sure .mjs also needs the flag in node12.  (Am away from test environment, so I'm basing that on what I've read.)

Comment: App Engine standard environment currently supports Node.js 12, which is in beta version. Have you tried using a [start script](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/runtime#application_startup) in your `package.json` to run the command with the `--experimental-modules` flag?. AFAIK, Node.js 12 requires you to use the `--experimental-modules` flag when enabling ES modules, but I think this may different for Node.js 13, as per [v12](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/esm.html#esm_enabling). and [v13](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v13.x/api/esm.html#esm_enabling) docs.